# Помогите решить ошибку PHP

Tags: php, функции, backend

Почему выводит
`num of errors - 1<br><ul><li>Here is an error</li></ul>`
Вот код

```
function check_input(array $numbers): array {
    $errors = [];
    // ...
    
    if ('validation not passed') {
        $errors[] = 'Here is an error'; 
    }
    
    // ...
    return $errors;
}

function print_errors(array $errors): void {
    echo 'num of errors - ' . count($errors);
    echo '<br><ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
}

$errors = check_input([1,1,-2,55,'opa', NULL, new stdClass()]);
if (!empty($errors)) {
    print_errors($errors);
    exit;
}
```

Как убрать br ul li....

Answer (score 0):

Убрать очень просто. Даже элементарно.

```
echo '<br><ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
```

заменить на

```
echo '' . implode('', $errors) . '';
```

Comment: Ну так вы дали ответ например если будет 1 число, а я делаю для массива, мне не нужно чтобы выводило все в 1 ряд

Comment: я ничего не понял из вашего комментария, вроде все слова знакомы, а смысл ускользает

Comment: Ваша команда будет выводить все в 1 ряд, а если например массив будет 1000 + елементов

Comment: то будут все в ряд. Вопрос был - как удалить br ul li. Я указал как. А в комментариях у вас сейчас совсем другая проблема, совершенно не связаная с вопросом. Постарайтесь задавать вопросы так, чтобы они как можно точнее отражали вашу проблему. Этим вы поможете в первую очередь себе.

Comment: Теперь если вы поняли в  чем проблема сможете мне помочь?

Comment: нет, я не совсем понял, в чем проблема. Если это выводится в html, то проблема одна. А если просто в текст, то ставьте после каждой строчки знак перевода каретки.

Comment: Извините сам затупил, я не выводил в html

Comment: Оказалось проблемы и не было)))

Comment: Ну во ...